# AngularJS: Unexpected identifier $http POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am having trouble with my http POST request in AngularJS. The function call to $http is giving me a SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. The unexpected identifier is referring to the line url: 'rating-add' in my $http call. 'rating-add' is a named url, so I don't know why it doesn't know this. This is the template:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.ratings = [];
    var data = $scope.myForm = {beer_name:'', score:'', notes:'', brewer:''};
    $scope.buttonClick = false;
    $scope.is_clicked = function() {
      $scope.buttonClick=true;
      console.log($scope.buttonClick)
    }
    $scope.submit_to_form = function() {
        $http({
          method: 'POST'
          url: 'rating-add'
          data: data
        });
    }
  })
  </script>
```

And the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from ratings.views import home, RatingCreate, delete, edit

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', RatingCreate.as_view(), name='rating-home'),
    url(r'rating/add/$', RatingCreate.as_view(), name='rating-add'),
    url(r'rating/delete/(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', delete , name='rating-delete'),
    url(r'rating/edit/(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', edit , name='rating-edit'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `,`. change this:

```
$http({
          method: 'POST'
          url: 'rating-add'
          data: data
        });
```

into:

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'rating/add/',
      data: data
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't your URL be /rating/add rather than rating-add?

Comment: @ke4ktz is right. you defined the path to the resource as `url(r'rating/add/$', RatingCreate.as_view(), name='rating-add')`